# Swiper разместить несколько слайдов по центру

Tags: javascript, css, swiper

Есть пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/dimansuvorlinda/pen/MWWaOqX)

Нужно сделать так, чтобы видимые фото были по центру, то есть так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`centeredSlides` не помог - он только одно фото центрирует. Как сделать так, чтобы было как на картинке?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  slidesPerView: 2,
});
```

```css
.swiper-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://www.artleo.com/mini/201804/422815.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://cache.desktopnexus.com/thumbseg/2040/2040636-bigthumbnail.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://www.rusdialog.ru/images/news/news_view/5107a4952d8cf8344551a6c9f4f80d0b.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://cache.desktopnexus.com/thumbseg/2040/2040636-bigthumbnail.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://www.rusdialog.ru/images/news/news_view/5107a4952d8cf8344551a6c9f4f80d0b.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://cache.desktopnexus.com/thumbseg/2040/2040636-bigthumbnail.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://www.rusdialog.ru/images/news/news_view/5107a4952d8cf8344551a6c9f4f80d0b.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```